# Failed to save and find any files for ./model_save. on my storage

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

hi i try save model file on my storage after train and codes run successful but cannot find any files like .h5 or ... on folder of model save and its empty

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function


import tensorflow as tf



import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

from bidi.algorithm import get_display
import arabic_reshaper
import unicodedata
import re
import numpy as np
import os
import time
import math 

print(tf.__version__)
```

```
save_dir = './model'
encoder_prefix = os.path.join(save_dir, "encoder_weights")
decoder_prefix = os.path.join(save_dir, "decoder_weights")
```

```
EPOCHS = 8
best_total_loss = 0.0071

for epoch in range(EPOCHS):
    start = time.time()
    
    hidden = encoder.initialize_hidden_state()
    total_loss = 0
    
    for (batch, (inp, targ)) in enumerate(dataset):
        loss = 0
        
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            enc_output, enc_hidden = encoder(inp, hidden)
            
            dec_hidden = enc_hidden
            
            dec_input = tf.expand_dims([targ_lang.word2idx['<start>']] * BATCH_SIZE, 1)       
            
            # Teacher forcing - feeding the target as the next input
            for t in range(1, targ.shape[1]):
                # passing enc_output to the decoder
                predictions, dec_hidden, _ = decoder(dec_input, dec_hidden, enc_output)
                
                loss += loss_function(targ[:, t], predictions)
                
                # using teacher forcing
                dec_input = tf.expand_dims(targ[:, t], 1)
        
        batch_loss = (loss / int(targ.shape[1]))
        
        total_loss += batch_loss
        
        variables = encoder.variables + decoder.variables
        
        gradients = tape.gradient(loss, variables)
        
        optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, variables))
        
        if batch % 100 == 0:
            print('Epoch {} Batch {} Loss {:.4f}'.format(epoch + 1,
                                                         batch,
                                                         batch_loss.numpy()))
    
    print('Epoch {} Loss {:.4f}'.format(epoch + 1, total_loss / N_BATCH))
    
    if best_total_loss > (total_loss / N_BATCH):
        
        best_total_loss = total_loss
        
        encoder.save_weights(encoder_prefix)
        decoder.save_weights(decoder_prefix)
        
        print('Saving weights at epoch {} with Loss {:.4f}'.format(epoch + 1, total_loss / N_BATCH))
        
    print('Time taken for 1 epoch {} sec\n'.format(time.time() - start))
```

hi i try save model file on my storage after train and codes run successful but cannot find any files like .h5 or ... on folder of model save and its empty

Comment: Are you sure *anything* is being saved? Your calls to `.save_weights()` are in an `if` block - are you sure the condition is being satisfied?

Comment: hi i dont know this is my python proj link can help me?

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1YDq5u6AbAzZw6dnurFaoZCgbIJKt2-UR?usp=sharing

Comment: You can find this out easily by printing the values of the individual variables and the result of the calculation just before you enter the `if` block.

Comment: ok tnx can u added block save code on my proj link for save model file?

Answer (score 0):

OK, first off, this line

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function
```

is ***completely*** irrelevant if you're using Python 3, which you absolutely should be doing. Python 2 was out of support over 3 years ago, and is obsolete.

Assuming you're using Python 3.6+, I'd highly recommend using f-strings ([tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals), [reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings)) for printing formatted output. It's a lot clearer when you're looking at them later on what exactly you're doing.

Now, to your problem. As I mentioned in the comments, your calls to the `.save_weights()` methods of `encoder` and `decoder` are in an `if` block - meaning, they only get called (and the data only gets saved) if the conditions for the `if` statement are true. You can determine their values, and hence whether or not the statement will be true, by two ways - using a debugger, and simply `print`ing their values. We'll go with the second way.

Directly before this line:

```
    if best_total_loss > (total_loss / N_BATCH):
```

insert these lines:

```
    print(f"best_total_loss: {best_total_loss}")
    print(f"total_loss: {total_loss}")
    print(f"N_BATCH: {N_BATCH}")
    print(f"best_total_loss > (total_loss / N_BATCH): {best_total_loss > (total_loss / N_BATCH):}")
```

Make sure they're *after* this line:

```
    print('Epoch {} Loss {:.4f}'.format(epoch + 1, total_loss / N_BATCH))
```

Now, you'll not only get the exact values of the variables in question, you'll get the result of the comparison in the `if` statement, so you'll know if the rest of that `if` block is even being executed.

If you just want to know if the block is being executed, simply run your code and look for the line produced by

```
        print('Saving weights at epoch {} with Loss {:.4f}'.format(epoch + 1, total_loss / N_BATCH))
```

If you don't see that line, nothing was saved. You can then go back and insert the other `print()` calls for debugging why that is the case.